# Ubuntu Software on 21.10 small display

Tags: 21.10

When I open Ubuntu Software Explore tab... I don't know the words to describe it... it's like the display is 1/2" wide by 2" tall, see picture. The Installed tab and Updates tab display correctly. How do I fix this please. Thank you. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have to use other software to manage software in all its kinds - deb, Snap, Flatpak.

I would suggest to install Plasma Discover by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install plasma-discover plasma-discover-backend-flatpak plasma-discover-backend-snap breeze
```

Then launch it and enjoy

[image: Plasma Discover on Ubuntu MATE 21.10]

instead of glossy cool-toyfull GNOME Software.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it.